# Use regex to match 3 characters in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a json payload that I need to match just the `SDC` in the `vdcLocation`.

```
{
    "cmdbID":"d01aacda21b7c181aaaaa16dc4bcbca",
    "serialNumber":"VBlock740-4239340361f4d-0f6d9d6ad46879",
    "vdcLocation":"Data Center-San Diego (SDC)"
}
```

Here's the code I have so far, what am I missing?

```
import json
with open('test-payload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    serialNumber = data["serialNumber"]
    dataCenter = data["vdcLocation"]
    splittedSerialNumber = serialNumber.split("-") # returns splitted list
    firstPart = splittedSerialNumber[0] # accessing the first part of the splitted list
    splittedDataCenter = dataCenter.split("-")
    lastPart = splittedDataCenter[1]
    vdcLocationOnly = if (re.match^('[SDC]')$):
        print(vdcLocationOnly)

print(serialNumber)
print(splittedSerialNumber)
print(firstPart)
print(splittedDataCenter)
print(lastPart)
```

Comment: If you just want to match `SDC` in input then you don't really need regex. Just use string function

Comment: your code is wrong here: "vdcLocationOnly = if (re.match^('[SDC]')$):"
Invalid syntax with the '^' sign, the '$' sign and re.match misses an argument, and still invalid syntax with the assignment to a variable with an if statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be something like the following:

```
import json
import re
with open('test-payload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    serialNumber = data["serialNumber"]
    dataCenter = data["vdcLocation"]
    splittedSerialNumber = serialNumber.split("-") # returns splitted list
    firstPart = splittedSerialNumber[0] # accessing the first part of the splitted list
    splittedDataCenter = dataCenter.split("-")
    lastPart = splittedDataCenter[1]
    if "SDC" in dataCenter:
        print("found SDC using in")

    if re.search(r'\(SDC\)$', dataCenter):
        print("found SDC using re")

print(serialNumber)
print(splittedSerialNumber)
print(firstPart)
print(splittedDataCenter)
print(lastPart)
```

The simplest approach would be to use `"SDC" in dataCenter`. But if your needs are a bit more complicated and you indeed need to use a regular expression then you probably want to use `re.search` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)).

Comment: tyvm, this worked out great. I added an else statement to the if for some additional logic I needed.